# Facebook Pixel Event ViewContent not firing properly on Product Page Shopify

Tags: jquery, shopify, facebook-pixel

I'm trying to figure out why my facebook event "ViewContent" is not firing properly. When I visit any product page, I can see the facebook pixel helper load the viewcontent, but after the page is done loading all the scripts it disappears. 
Upon page refresh it will show the event being fired. Which is weird.
It also keeps throwing a duplicate ID in my console whereas I do not have a duplicate ID anywhere else.

My ID is pasted in the online store > preferences > Facebook Pixel

```
<!-- Additional Scripts -->
   {% if first_time_accessed %}
   <script>
    fbq('trackSingle', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX48', 'Purchase', {
     content_type: 'product',
     value: '{{ total_price | money_without_currency }}',
     currency: '{{ shop.currency }}'
     });
   </script>
   {%endif%}
<!-- end additional Scripts -->
<!-- code in product.liquid-->
   <!-- FB -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $( '#AddToCartForm' ).submit(function() {
        var customVal = $(this).find('#AddToCart').attr('data-price');
        fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
         content_ids: [{% for item in cart.items %}'{{item.variant_id}}',{% endfor %}],
         content_type: 'product',
         value: customVal,
         currency: 'USD'
         });
       });
   </script>
  <!-- fb -->
```

If you visit the site [www.gurunanda.com](https://www.gurunanda.com) and use the facebook pixel helper tool it'll show view content is loading on a product page but disappears after everything is fully loaded. It also shows dual firing of events. Such as addtocart and viewContent (once product page is reloaded).

Answer (score 1):

Its possible view `ViewContent`data.

[image: Pixel Helper]

However, you have duplicate Pixel on the page. (Pixel ID: 1598023190518448)

Check your console, and review all facebook pixel entries
[image]

Comment: Seems that second time is called from `trekkie`

Comment: Thanks for checking it out for me, I think the trekkie is from inputing the ID in the 'admin' section of shopify. I downloaded a shopify theme and checked the pixels and it was firing perfectly. so it's def something in my theme. Just don't know where its happening.